# How can I get a user to input values to this average program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have been trying to get a user to enter numbers into the average program but am having difficulty. Would I need to make and array to store the values in? The code I have written so far is below, at the moment I am trying to parse and Int value which is not working any suggestions, would prefer if people just gave explanations rather the code. Many Thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apples {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int test [];
    int grade=0;
    int i=0;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (i<10){
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for average");
    test = sc.nextInt[]();
    System.out.println(average(test));
    i++;
    }
}
public static int average(int...numbers){arguments
    int total=0;
    for(int x:numbers)
        total+=x;
    return total/numbers.length;
}
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: read the tutorials or your book. You're guessing on how to use arrays, Scanner, everything. Guessing never works. For instance, you have to initialize the array before using it. You need to read up on how to handle array items, which you're not doing. You're not making Scanner calls correctly, i.e., `sc.nextInt[]()` doesn't make sense. You're creating a complete program that's full of errors without testing that each line works before adding a new line. You want to either use an IDe which checks for compilation errors with each new bit of code, or compile frequently, and not add...

Comment: ... new code to bad code until you've first fixed your compilation errors. But again most important, read on the tools you're using before trying to use them, because as I've stated above, simply guessing is not how you succeed at doing this.

Comment: Scanner uses `.next()`, `.nextInt()`, `.nextLine()` methods, but not `.nextInt[]()` which isn't valid Java. The Scanner API will tell you all the methods that are available to it. Arrays need to be initialized before they can be used, e.g. `String[] foo = new String[4];`, else the variable is null, but any tutorial or book will already tell you this and show you this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks for the replies I will read more. I actually made a mistake by including the scanner call (was meant to edit it out). But will get back get back to the books.

Comment: Good, the books will help you, and again, don't try to create a whole program at once. Add lines and test that it compiles incrementally. You never want to add new code to code that currently doesn't compile, which is what you were doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code:

1) `int test [];` You create an `int[]` refference but you never initialize it.

2) `test = sc.nextInt[]();` This does not make any sence and causes your code to not compile.
 I am assuming you want to add every number the user enters to your array so you should do: `test[i] = sc.nextInt();` instead. The `test[i]` part accesses the index `i` of your array and you assign it the value of `sc.nextInt();` which is the next `int` the user inputs.

3) You calculate the average inside this means that everytyime someone enters a number you recalculate the average. What you should do is move it outside the loop.

4) Your `average()` method is fine except that you need to pass it an int[] as the arguement.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have an understanding of it much better now.

Comment: Sorry cannot seem to do it at the moment as I do not have 15 reputations yet. When I do get them I will up vote.

Comment: How do I accept it? It will not let me up vote it as mentioned previously as I do not have 15 reputation yet?

Comment: under the vote arrows there is a "check" button. You have to click it